# Navigating to fiori smart template

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a fiori application with an XML View. On press of the buttonvon the front view of the app, I need to navigate to fiori smart template(the one on SAP scn explored example) How to do that. I can do view to view navigation. I can navigate to the URL(of the smart template example on the explored) but I need to load that app on click on the button on my application. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

If your app is to run on the SAP Fiori Launchpad, you require target mapping and then intent-based navigation. 
If the app doesn’t need to run on the SAP Fiori Launchpad, you would require a component container in which the Smart Template app can load.